# Chrome - Copy/Paste - Maintains Styling When Pasted Into Word

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, copy-paste

When I copy and paste from my app into word, it maintains the css styles.
This is only an issue from chrome.

Is there a workaround for this?
For both Ctr+C and from Context menu?

Comment: See https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Control-the-formatting-when-you-paste-text-20156a41-520e-48a6-8680-fb9ce15bf3d6

Comment: Can you try `CTRL+ T` immediately after pasting in Word to keep only text?

Comment: I can't force the users to do the CTRL+T. But I may be able to change the application settings since it is an internal application.

Comment: If you put your first comment as an answer I'll give your the credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can press `CTRL + T` immediately after pasting in Word to keep only text.

The [default paste options in Word](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Control-the-formatting-when-you-paste-text-20156a41-520e-48a6-8680-fb9ce15bf3d6) can also be configured to keep only text.